# Integrate .aar file in multi-module android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module project in android studio and I want to integrate an `.aar` file in a module which is beeing referenced as library in the App module. The project structure is namely:

```
- module1
- module2
- module3
- module4
- moduleApp
```

The module1 is used as library reference in the module2.

`build.gradle module2`:

```
  dependencies {
        ...
        compile project(':module1')
    }
```

The module2 and the other modules are referenced in th App module.

`build.gradle moduleApp`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project(':module2')
    compile project(':module3')
    compile project(':module4')
}
```

I need to integrate an .aar file as library in the module1, since it is required from the module1 impementation. I do the integration in the normal manner:

`build.gradle module1`:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
} 

dependencies {
    compile 'package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar'
}
```

However when I run the `gradle sync` I receive the error:

```
failed to resolve package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar in module2
failed to resolve package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar in moduleApp
```

What should I do to let module2 and moduleApp find the .aar library? Should I include something more in their the build.gradle files?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
dependencies {
   compile 'package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar'
}
```

to:

```
dependencies {
   compile ('package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar'){
      transitive=true
   }
}
```

Alternatively, just add:

```
compile 'package.name.of.aar:myLibrary@aar'
```

to module2 and moduleApp

Comment: flatDir{dirs 'libs'} is a valid repository. Under libs folder in module1 I put the myLibrary.aar file. module1 is not an .aar lib. It is a module with code which needs myLibrary.aar.

Comment: I apologize, I completely misunderstood your question. You should probably use `transitive = true` as shown in the answer I linked to. Updating my answer.

Comment: I have already tried your second approach and it does not work. I will apply transisive, but I wonder if I should set it on "compile ':module1' when addind it as dependency in module2 and moduleApp, because that is the module beeing referenced as library in other modules.

Comment: is there a way to know package name of my aar

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an aar file with a `flat repo`, **in all modules** which use the module1 (in your case module2 and the app) where you need the aar file you have to add in your `build.gradle` the repository:

```
  repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'libs'
            }
        }
```

and add the dependency:

```
dependencies {
   compile(name:'nameOfYourAARFileWithoutExtension', ext:'aar')
 }
```

Comment: Directory libs lies in the module1 at the same level with build.gradle, it is namely defined as relative path. The other modules have not a libs directory with the .aar file. I think it could be defined in other modules as absolute path, but it does not help me, I have ruled out this possibility. Moreover, I do not need it in the other modules, I want only to prevent gradle build from failing. That is the issue in this case.

Comment: Move your aar into a maven repo. It resolves any issue